# namespace not defined typescript - angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript, module, controller, referenceerror

I really don't know what i'm doing wrong D:
I've a class inside a module but when i try to create an object of that type (in the controller) it say "namespace not defined"

namespace and class

```
module Acquisti {
export class AcqCliente {
    private descrizione: string;
    private _prezzo: number;

    constructor(descrizione, prezzo) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this._prezzo = prezzo;
    }

    set prezzo(prezzo: number) {
        this._prezzo = prezzo;
    }

    get prezzo(): number {
        return this._prezzo;
    }

    stampa(): string {
        return "- " + this.descrizione + "   " + this.prezzo + " euro";
    }
}}
```

I try to create the object in the controller

```
/// <reference path="../obj/AcqCliente.ts" />

app.controller('democontroller', function ($scope) {
    var obj = new Acquisti.AcqCliente(desc, price);
    .
    .
    .
});
```

And when i run, console's message is:

```
angular.js:15018 ReferenceError: Acquisti is not defined
at b.$scope.aggiungiProdottoInFattura (controller.ts:17)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15869), <anonymous>:4:411)
at e (angular.js:28101)
at b.$eval (angular.js:18838)
at b.$apply (angular.js:18937)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:28106)
at ng (angular.js:3795)
at HTMLButtonElement.d (angular.js:3783)
```